# Auto detection Jackson for Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I am working on a project that uses Spring framework and Jackson. However, I was not able to find a place, where it is being plugged. I looked at many examples on the web and most of them use bean of class `org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter` to allow deserialization of `@ResponseBody`.
So, I was not able to find any references to `MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter`.

My question: Will spring framework automatically use Jackson if it will find it on its classpath to convert JSON into `@ResponseBody` object?

What are other ways how Jackson can be enabled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you wire up your spring project using `@EnableWebMvc` or via XML by using the tag `<mvc:annotation-driven />` you enable a bunch of features. You can read the detailed list of features in the [original Spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-enable).

One of the features that are enabled is the support for `@RequestBody` method parameters and `@ResponseBody` method return values. This is done via the `HttpMessageConverter` component and the feature is enabled for methods that are annotated with `@RequestMapping` or `@ExceptionHandler`.

The following lists the converters that are registered by default:

- `ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter` converts byte arrays.
- `StringHttpMessageConverter` converts strings.
- `ResourceHttpMessageConverter` converts to/from `org.springframework.core.io.Resource` for all media types.
- `SourceHttpMessageConverter` converts to/from a `javax.xml.transform.Source`.
- `FormHttpMessageConverter` converts form data to/from a MultiValueMap.
- `Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter` converts Java objects to/from XML — added if JAXB2 is present on the classpath.
- `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` (or `MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter`) converts to/from JSON — added if Jackson 2 (or Jackson) is present on the classpath.
- `AtomFeedHttpMessageConverter` converts Atom feeds — added if Rome is present on the classpath.
- `RssChannelHttpMessageConverter` converts RSS feeds — added if Rome is present on the classpath.

So, if you have a *web enabled* project with Jackson available on the classpath, Spring will automatically convert return values from a controller-method that is annotated with `@ResponseBody` (if the client caller accepts JSON that is which means that the accept header typically must be set to  `application/json`).

If you wish to override the `HttpMessageConverter`s you can implement the following:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class YourConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
        public void configureMessageConverters(
                List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {

            // Do your magic, override your stuff
        }
}
```

For a good introduction on how to customize e.g. the Jackson converter you can read [this article from DZone about Customizing HttpMessageConverters with Spring Boot and Spring MVC](http://java.dzone.com/articles/customizing).

Comment: Can I override MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter, if I need some customization?

Comment: Thanks! +some characters :)